# jQuery validate - onclick function issue

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a PayPal form and I would like to change the "submit" button image to something different when a user clicks on it (providing the form is valid).

The issue I am having is that when I add the .validate() and click function to the script, it breaks everything. Nothing validates anymore + the submit button does not change.

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form" method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr><td><b>Registration Code</b>:</td><td><input type="text" size="25" name="os0" id="os0" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>E-Mail Address</b>:</td><td><input type="text" size="25" name="os1" id="os1" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Confirm E-Mail</b>:</td><td><input type="text" size="25" name="os2" id="os2" value=""></td></tr>
<div id="error_messages"></div>
<input name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" type="image" src="/images/paypal.gif">
</td></tr></table></form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#paypal_form').validate();

$('#submit').click(function()
{
    if ($("#paypal_form").valid() === true)
    {
        document.getElementById('submit').src = "http://www.example.com/images/loading.gif";
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("RegCodeRegex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[bB][A-Za-z]{6}[-][A-Za-z][0-9]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Invalid registration code!");


$('#paypal_form').validate({

rules: {

    os0: {
        required: true,
        RegCodeRegex: true
    },

    os1: {
        required: true
    },

    os2: {
        required: true,
        equalTo: "#os1"
    }
},

messages: {

    os0: {
        RegCodeRegex: "Invalid Registration Code!"
    },

    os1: {
        required: "Please enter in your email address<br>"
    },

    os2: {
        required: "Please confirm your email address",
        equalTo: "Email addresses do not match!"
    }
},

errorContainer: "#error_messages",
errorLabelContainer: "#error_messages"
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is this jQuery.validate a plugin? If so, could you provide a link to the plugin, and also show your js includes. You'd be surprised at how often errors occur by including .js files in the wrong order.

Comment: edited above code with includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called `$('#paypal_form').validate` twice, one without argument, one with argument. Removing the first one should make it work.

Comment: ah yes, however removing the line "$('#paypal_form').validate();" still does not solve my issue.

Comment: @Dave  It should.  I setup a a jfiddle and Hui Zheng is correct.  http://jsfiddle.net/WNwh7/  The image for the submit button obviously doesn't load, but jquery validate is working as it is supposed to work.

Comment: @KyleRogers Thanks for your verification:)

Comment: @kyle any ideas how to get the button image to change?

Comment: @Dave It's recommended to change button's CSS style instead of hard-coded url. That way you don't have to modify url in JS(instead, modify in CSS) when you decide to change image.

Comment: @Hui Zheng - I only wish for the button to change is form is vaild - not sure how to do this using css.

Comment: @Dave here you go.  I removed the jquery validate for the registration code, but you can just add that back.  http://jsfiddle.net/WNwh7/2/

Comment: @Dave be sure check Hui's answer as correct as he answered your question correctly.  Thanks.